# Wavelength and Lattice constant - need to be the similar magnitudes to have interference?

Tags: interference, wavelength

I was taught that they need to have similar magnitudes but I did an exercise last week and the magnitudes were different by 3 decimal places. Before I also noticed them being either the same or maybe one decimal place different.

So, is it actually true that the need to have similar magnitudes? And if so, to what extent? Lastly, *why* do they need to be of similar magnitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first off: What you are doing is called, I hope, x-ray interference.

In x-ray interference, we send a beam of light of known frequency and wavelength to a lattice. This beam gets reflected and scattered from the lattice atoms, and the ones that manage to go to the detector result in constructive interference if they follow Bragg's law:
$$2d\sin(\theta)=n\lambda,\ \ n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$
where $d$ is the lattice constant (the separation between lattice atoms), $\theta$ is the incident angle and $\lambda$ is the wavelength of the beam.

So far, there is no need for $d$ and $\lambda$ to be similar. But let's consider the following scenario: If I want to see that a condition is indeed a constructive interference, I must vary the incident angle to both positive and negative sides until I see a destructive interference.

This means that we also find $\theta',\theta''$ such that
$$
2d\sin(\theta')=\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)\lambda,\ \ 
2d\sin(\theta'')=\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)\lambda
$$

So, let's see the difference between two destructive interference points. We already know $\theta$, inserting that,
$$
2d\sin(\theta')=2d\sin(\theta)-\frac{\lambda}{2},\ \ 
2d\sin(\theta'')=2d\sin(\theta)+\frac{\lambda}{2}
$$
$$
\sin(\theta')=\sin(\theta)-\frac{\lambda}{4d},\ \ 
\sin(\theta'')=\sin(\theta)+\frac{\lambda}{4d}
$$

Here we know that $\theta \in \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ because this is the angle $\vec{k}$ of the wave makes with the normal of the surface, and therefore it must be in this range.

So, if we want to be able to see both constructive and destructive interference, and this is the only way we can identify one from the other, we have the following condition:

$$0\leq\sin(\theta')\leq 1,\ \ 0\leq\sin(\theta'')\leq 1$$
therefore
$$0\leq\frac{\lambda}{4d}\leq 1$$
from both.

This is equivalent to, because $d,\lambda\geq 0$ physically:
$$\lambda \leq 4d$$

Now, for another thought, we cannot have the difference too small, because in that case, we wouldn't be able to detect changes that small in angle. This means that we also cannot have $\lambda$ extremely smaller than $d$. For clarity, we can detect changes in angle that is less than $\frac{1}{1000}$ of a degree, which is approximately $\frac{1}{60000}$ radians, making the least $\frac{\lambda}{d}$ ratio for an effective interferometer about the same.

Combining these two, we need a wavelength slightly smaller than the lattice parameter so that we can actually verify our findings. Otherwise, if we cannot see destructive interference as well, and we cannot claim we have found a constructive interference either, and then there won't be a lattice parameter to be calculated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So that means, the only relationship is that d is greater than lambda, right?

Comment: Yeah, but also going for a wavelength too small is not that good of an idea.

Comment: Could you explain why it's not a good idea? How I see it now, we could use all wavelengths smaller than d...even a baseball that has a wavelength of around 10^-32 or so. Something isn't adding up...

Comment: No you're correct, I'm just being careful. We can't produce wavelengths that short, but even if we did, we shouldn't try using them for lattice interferometry.